# Problems with insert cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am counting the number of features in a geodabase. I  am triying to insert the feature name and the count inside a dbf table which has only two fields: "FEAT" (Text field which containts the feature name) and "COUNT" (short field which contains the feature count).

This is my code:

```
  listlayers= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()        
  for feat in listlayers:
    count = 0
    count = arcpy.GetCount_management(feat)
    feat = str(feat)
    if count > 0:
      print feat + " has " + str(count) + " entries"
      with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(destinationgeneraltable, ("FEAT","COUNT")) as icursor:
         icursor.insertRow((feat,count))
    else:
      print feat + " is void"
```

I use an insert cursor to insert these records inside this table but it fails without any error message.

Comment: What does your destination DBF file look like after this?

Comment: Thanks radouxju the dbf is void an blocked, It has a block file.

Comment: Create cursor outside loop Make sure. Dbf. Is short

Answer (score 4):

getCount returns an object, not an integer. You need to use :

```
count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile).getOutput(0))
```

then I would not use feat = str(feat)

Comment: Thansk radouxju it is working.